# Does Hinduism view homosexuality as a karmic punishment?

Tags: karma, homosexuality

Ok this might be a bit controversial post. I have some friends who recently came and told me they're gay although they don't look gay as stereotypes would like us to believe. They look just like other strapping young men .

But most of them expressed their dismissal about their sexuality , their inability to change it and also their regret because it robs them of freedom that comes with being heterosexual (straight), respect and image in society, and also of opportunities like marriage , love , kids , etc that we take for granted

which has let me wondering If homosexuality more often than not brings so much suffering to men who suffer from it , is it a karmic punishemnt for some misdoing in previous life ?

A hindu brother told me its punishment for separating lovers in past life, 
someone else said its punishment for violating a woman's respect , rape etc

Is it true ??

What do hindu sources say about it ? thanks

Comment: If homosexuality is mentioned as a disease then it is a karmic punishment because diseases are nothing but remnants of bad karmas. But i doubt if any scriptures mention homosexuality as a disease or not.

Comment: All I am saying is since a homosexual man has several shortcomings as compared to a heterosexual man
1) Heterosexual men have more rights, social acceptance in society as compared to gay men
2) gay men are more likely to have diseases like aids and mental issues like depression, anxiety and more likely to commit suicide due to social ostrazication . Hence i feel homosexuality can only be a product of bad karma